# How can I run a lot of functions in sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, q

Maybe this question is duplicate. I found a lot of similar questions, but no one can actually solve my problem. This is my task:

```
function animate(){
  $ul.each(function(){
     $(this).find('li').each(function(){
          //animate block
          $(this).animate({top:'-100%'},100,function(){
             $(this).css({top:'100%'});
          });
          //endblock
        });
     });
}
```

As you may know, the 'animate block' functions will run at a same time. I want them to run in sequence. How can I achieve that?

I have read jQuery 'deferred', 'Q' relate article, but still confusing.

Sorry for my English.

---------addition------

If I want to run animate function several times, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid jQuery's awkward `.queue()`/`.dequeue()`, then you can build a promise chain from a jQuery collection of your `<li>` elements.

```
function animate($ul) {
    var p = $.when(); //resolved starter promise
    $("li", $ul).each(function(i, li) {
        p = p.then(function() {
            return $(li).animate({ top:'-100%' }, 100, function() {
                return $(li).css({ top:'100%' });
            }).promise();
        });
    });
    return p;
}
```

As the chain settles, the animations will occur in sequence.

More elegantly, you can extend jQuery to have a `.reduce()` method, adopted from `Array.prototype`.

```
jQuery.fn.reduce = Array.prototype.reduce;
```

Then, build the required promise chain by invoking `.reduce()` on the jQuery collection.

```
function animate($ul) {
    return $("li", $ul).reduce(function(p, li) {//wow, jQuery has a .reduce() method!
        return p.then(function() {
            //Here, perform the required animation and return a promise of its completion.
            return $(li).animate({top:'-100%'}, 100, function() {
                $(li).css({top:'100%'});
            }).promise();
        });
    }, $.when());//Resolved starter promise, ie p in the first iteration of .reduce() .
}
```

This pattern is well worth learning as it has many applications.

In both examples, the outermost `return` allows you to chain `.then()` wherever `animate()` is called :

```
animate($("ul")).then(function() {
    //do something when all the <li> animations have completed.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution using `queue()` function.

This function waits until the animation completes and then executes it's contents.

```js
var anim = function(i) {
  $('.test').eq(i).animate({'top':'20px'}, 350).queue(function() {
    i++;
    anim(i);
    $(this).dequeue();
  });
}
anim(0);
```

```css
.test {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float: left;
  margin-right:10px;
  background-color:green;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var last_deferred = $.Deferred();
last_deferred.resolve();

$ul.each(function(){
    $(this).find('li').each(function(){
         var deferred = $.Deferred(),
             $that = $(this);
         last_deferred.then(function() {
             $that.animate({top:'-100%'},100,function(){
                $(this).css({top:'100%'});
                deferred.resolve();
             });
         });
         last_deferred = deferred;
    });
});
```

**Explanation:** here I use 2 important features of deferred objects `.then` and `.resolve`. When you call `.resolve();` the deferred object will fire all handlers assigned to it via `.then`. So what happens is that I first define "dummy" deferred which I immediately resolve. If deferred object is resolved then adding a handler via `.then` will automatically make it run. So what happens is this

1. `last_deferred` is defined and resolved
2. Temporary `deferred` is created
3. Add `.then` handler to `last_deferred`
4. `.then` handler is fired and after some things it does it resolves `deferred` (thus triggers `.then` on `deferred`)
5. `last_deferred` is redefined to be `deferred`
6. go back to 2.

So this is kind of an asynchronous loop (because `.animate` is an asynchronous operation). In each step you say "when previous `deferred` is resolved tell it to resolve the next one".

Comment: Yes, this can solve my problem. But could you please tell me how this work? I try to read the jQuery API, but still confusing.

Comment: @JamesYin I've updated the answer. I hope it is clear now, let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: You save my life. Now, I totally understand what 'deferred' can do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's no need for that inner `$.Deferred()` as a promise of completion of the animation is more readily available from `$(that).animate(...).promise()`. Also, the inner `.each()` can be purged by initially forming a jQuery collection of all relevant LI elements. jQuery will preserve the correct order for you. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.queue()` , `$.map()` , `.delay()` ; substituting `window.innerHeight` for `100` , `px` unit for `%` unit at `.animate()` ; substituting `.animate` for `.css` at `complete` callback

```js
var ul = $("ul");
ul.queue("_fx", $.map(ul.find("li"), function(el, i) {
  return function(next) {
    return $(el).animate({
      top: "-" + window.innerHeight / 10 + "px"
    }, 100, function() {       
      $(this).delay(100).animate({
        top: window.innerHeight - $(this).height() * 1.5 + "px"
      }, 100, next);
    })
  };
})).dequeue("_fx");
```

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
}
ul li {
  top: 150px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  padding 8px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
  <li>a
  </li>
  <li>b
  </li>
  <li>c
  </li>
  <li>d
  </li>
  <li>e
  </li>
  <li>f
  </li>
  <li>g
  </li>
</ul>
```